# Postgresql14 copying files to a new database with only static files

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-14

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thrc6.png)I have a problem with Postgresql14. Of course, I'm stupid and I gave up. One day an error occurred and several files were destroyed and I couldn't access psql from bash in any way. There were errors in the log and I fought for 3 days but I gave up. I took and saved all the database files from the /var/lib/posgtresql/14/main folder. I'm attaching it in the photo. I set up a new base and it fired up. My question is, is there any way I can extract table and database data from the files I copied and insert them into the newly created one?

I'm trying to find a way but I don't know if it can be done this way. I tried several times but unfortunately when I checked the database it was still clean and nothing appeared. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

I copied the base and global files to new database files, restarted, but still nothing appears

Comment: 1) **Do not use images for textual information**, copy and past as text. 2) This is going to need a lot  more information, **add as text to your question text** the following: a) What files where destroyed?  b) `psql` is the Postgres command line client, so not sure what *... access psql from bash in any way.* means? You could not  run  `psql` or you could not connect to Postgres server? c) Define set up new base? d) *I tried several times ...*. Tried what?

Comment: `errors`.... Care to share?

Comment: If you actually lost files, this is not a task for a rookie. You need a specialist and lots of ready money.